# Elasticache Redis only making 24 connections per host

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, redisson

I have a service with multipl host calling redis in AWS Elasticache and I did not modify the initial pool size so it should be at its default which is the following according to this doc: https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/2.-configuration#241-cluster-settings

Master Connection Pool:

Min: 24
Max: 64

Slave

Min: 24
Max: 64

Redisson Config:

```
config
      .useClusterServers()
      .addNodeAddress(s"rediss://$host:$port")
      .setRetryAttempts(1)
      .setRetryInterval(75)
      .setConnectTimeout(5000)
      .setTimeout(150)
```

However when looking at my elasticache metrics I see that the currConnections only goes up to 24 connections from each host and only increases if I add extra capacity. This happened even thou the service was chocking and Redisson was reporting

`RedisTimeoutException: Unable to acquire connection! RedissonPromise [promise=ImmediateEventExecutor$ImmediatePromise@287d512b(failure: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException)]Increase connection pool size`

Im not certain why this happened and why Redisson did not increase the connection pool if it was having problems up to its max of 50. Am I misunderstanding how the pool works or metrics are reported? How can I fix this as my pool should already have the capacity needed.